# Firebase function when updating another child field in document - change.before.ref.parent is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm very new at Firestore functions and I started using them in tandem with Realtime Database. What I want to achieve - if any field under '**scores**' collection is changed (in this example, 't1' or 't2'), then the 'round' field should be incremented by 1. The document looks like this:

[image]

This is my function:

```
exports.onScoreChange = functions.database
.ref('games/{gameId}/scores')
.onWrite((change, context) => {
    console.log('Score of either player has changed');
    var round = change.before.ref.parent('gameInfo/round').get('round') + 1; 
    console.log('Rounds so far: ' + round);
    return change.ref.parent('gameInfo/round').set(round);
});
```

When I look at logs, the function is fired because I can see the message in logs 'Score of either player has changed', but then I get this error:

```
change.before.ref.parent is not a function
```

My flow of logic was that I should go one "step" above in the document so I can access other fields that belong to the game 'gameInfo' collection - and then I can access field 'round' and change it. What is wrong with the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Error you are getting is because `change.before.ref.parent` is a property it is not a method refer [this official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#reading_the_previous_value) This can be avoided if you have used typescript while creating firebase function. Instead of accessing like that I Recommend you to access with `child`

```
const roundRef = change.before.ref.parent?.child("gameInfo/round"); //⇐ Using child
```

The parent of `scores` is `{gameId}` so the same as that `gameInfo/round` will be the child of `{gameId}`.

So the updated function will be :

```
exports.onScoreChange = functions.database.ref("games/{gameId}/scores")
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
      console.log("Score of either player has changed");
      const roundRef = change.before.ref.parent?.child("gameInfo/round");
      return roundRef?.transaction((round) => {
        return round + 1;
      });
    });
```

Comment: I actually cobbled some solution together: https://justpaste.it/ctjpl, but your solution is much more elegant and easier to understand on how to access fields within the same document, thank you!!